# Custom download functionality for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, file, plugins, download

I am trying to create functionality for a custom made `wordpress` plugin where when user clicks on the download button appropriate file from the directory should be downloaded related to that post.

I don't want the file to be directly accessible from the URL and want only authorize user to be allowed to download file.

```
class DownloadM{
function __construct(){

}
function setDownload($file){
    //$file = ROOT_DIR_PATH."wp-content/uploads/2016/07/PDF.zip";
    echo "<a href='".$file."'>Click here to download</a>";
    ob_start();

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=PDF.zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    flush();
    ob_clean();
    readfile($file);
} 
}
```

The file is properly getting downloaded if I placed the link in the `href` tag or accessed it from the URL directly.

But when I put the file in the header to auto download it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for you:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```